# Problemas com legendas divididas no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legenda-de-gráfico

Olá, gostaria do auxílio de vocês quanto a legendas usando o `ggplot2`. Estou querendo extrair uma legenda para utilizar em outro gráfico que usa `plot_grid`, porém eu não sei o porquê, mas o mesmo código funciona (Figura 1) e deixa de funcionar (Figura 2), e as vezes até usando o `+theme()`  divide as legendas (Figura 2). Para `+theme()`eu utilizo: `theme(text = element_text(family="Times New Roman",size=rel(4)),legend.text = element_text(family="Times New Roman",size=18),legend.position = "bottom")`.

[image: Figura 1]

**Figura 1**

[image: Figura 2]

**Figura 2**

segue o código:

```
expres<-expression(italic(hat(Y)) == -1.314 * x^"***" ~ ~~italic(R)^{2} == 0.96)

legenda<-expand.grid(Y=rev(seq(-1.0,-.2,.2)),x=rev(seq(-1.0,-.2,.2)),tipo=1:2)

ggplot(legenda,aes(x=Y,y=x))+
  geom_line(aes(linetype=as.factor(tipo),colour=as.factor(tipo)),size=1)+
  scale_linetype_manual(name="Tipo:",labels=c(eval(parse(text=paste('expression(',expres,')',sep=""))),"reta 1:1"),values=c(1,2),breaks=c(1,2))+
  scale_color_manual(name="Tipo:",labels=c(eval(parse(text=paste('expression(',expres,')',sep=""))),"reta 1:1"),values=c("black","blue"),breaks = c(1,2))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```